# Angular Deployment not working

Tags: angular, express, deployment, webpack, mean-stack

I've deployed my Angular 4 App using WebPack, but when I try to open it I get these Errors
[image]

**index.js**

```
...
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  if (process.env.live) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
  } else {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/src/index.html'));
  }
});
...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is most likely caused by your server trying to serve the index.html file for all your resources (scripts included)

Comment: @LLai I think so, what can I do to fix this? I've updated some information.

Comment: Check the paths. In your developer tools (F12) --> Network  make sure the requests are going to the right paths.

Comment: Can you post more of your index.js? Also does your index.html have a `<base href="/">` tag?